# JQuery removing child elements

Tags: jquery

I have this structure

```
<section class="main">
   <div class="first" />
   <h1 class="subtitle" />
   <div class="body" />
   <div class="module" />
</section>
<section class="main">
   <div class="first" />
   <h1 class="subtitle" />
   <div class="body" />
   <div class="module" />
</section>
```

I need to remove .body and .subtitle only in the ONE of the sections.

How can I do this using jquery?

Thanks

Comment: in the first one for example.

Answer (score 8):

Try using `.eq` to pick right main section and do a `.find`. See below,

```
$('.main').eq(0)  //use 1 if you want to remove from second section
          .find('.body, .subtitle').remove();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/dtFsb/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.body, .subtitle', '.main:eq(0)').remove();
```

So, the code above means you will remove form the first section, if you want to remove from the second change `eq(0)` to `eq(1)`.
[Working](http://jsfiddle.net/gTMVh/)

Comment: `$( ".body, .subtitle", ".main:eq(0)")`

Comment: @Esailija Thanks I forgot that can be selected in this way.

Comment: You should use `eq()` in place of `:eq`. Look [here](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Provide a context via the second parameter. In this case, our context will be the first `.main` element:

```
$(".body, .subtitle", ".main:first").remove();
```